# Future of WINAPI MFC ALT WIN-FORMS WPF in Windows 8?

Tags: wpf, windows, mfc

I'm about to start a long term windows application project but not sure which way to go, i have to kept in mind due to long term project the technology i will choose must be supported in upcoming windows 8. The project can be created on any of these WINAPI MFC ALT WIN-FORMS WPF more of less a little but my main concern is a long support at least as long as windows 8 comes out and continue. I personally wanted to go with WPF but i'm kinda scared that everyone on internet is talking that WPF is going to dead because of Microsoft new HTML5/JS hype. I don't know why Microsoft has choose HTML5/JS as their PLATFORM for windows development in windows 8 (i personally don't think HTML5 is not capable enough to create AAA windows applications).
Which is most safe can any one tell me through his experience

WINAPI MFC ALT WIN-FORMS WPF ? Which one

Comment: Too localised: this should be answered and the Build Conference MS are holding. Until then *no one knows*, and after the question becomes uninteresting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have choose wpf with mvvm pattern for our frontend technology.

at least the frontend technology depends on your application requirements :)